# Squid 3 block images while using parent proxy

Tags: proxy, routes, squid

I have a squid server set up to route all my requests through another proxy without having to add the authentication for the proxy from the client.

This is my squid config

```
acl local_net src all
pid_filename ussquidi
acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid3/bad-sites.squid"
acl FORBIDDEN_EXT urlpath_regex \.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico)$ 
http_access allow local_net
http_access deny bad_url
http_access deny FORBIDDEN_EXT
http_port 8901
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8
never_direct allow all
cache_peer zproxy.luminati.io parent 22225 0 no-query default proxy-only login=lum-customer-strawhouselabs-zone-gen:xxxxxxxx
cache_peer_access zproxy.luminati.io allow local_net
```

The problem is when connecting through this proxy, I am trying to block images as well as a list of urls I have deemed as "bad", as you can see by the bad_url acl and FORBIDDEN_EXT acl. Unfortunately neither images or the bad urls are being blocked by the squid proxy, they still show in the squid logs as a TCP/MISS that is allowed to go through to the final destination.

I think I am missing something about using squid ACL's with the cache_peer parent settings, it does not seem to use any of the http_access deny rules I have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use cache_peer_access to deny request using your deny acls

```
cache_peer_access zproxy.luminati.io deny bad_url FORBIDDEN_EXT
```

try this above the line

```
cache_peer_access zproxy.luminati.io allow local_net
```

so your config should look like

```
cache_peer zproxy.luminati.io parent 22225 0 no-query default proxy-only login=lum-customer-strawhouselabs-zone-gen:xxxxxxxx
cache_peer_access zproxy.luminati.io deny bad_url FORBIDDEN_EXT
cache_peer_access zproxy.luminati.io allow local_net
```